# How to pull data from mongodb using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a data in mongoDb like below:

```
{
 "_id": "5fe1cf1230ecc74464f07c7e"
"subjects": [
    "english",
    "math",
    "social",
    "science"
  ],
}
```

I want to remove a single data from subject, and i write a code like below:

```
exports.reldata = async (req, res) => {
const subject = req.body.subjects;
console.log(req.params.id);
SingleCourse.find({ _id: req.params.id }).updateOne(
{
  $pull: { subjects: [...subject] },
},
(err, doc) => {
  console.log("from pull", doc);
  }
 );
}
```

In console it returns me a success message like below:

```
from pull { n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
```

But when I look in my database, Data still exists there. It does not remove a data. Please can anyone help to solve my problem.
I'm using nodejs, express, mongodb. I'm using postman to send data

Answer (score 0):

The fllowing is myworking code

```
SingleCourse.update( 
  { _id: req.params.id},
  {  $pull: { subjects: [...subject] } },
  { safe: true },
  function callback(err, obj) {
     console.log(obj);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $pull is an array update operator that cannot be used with `updateOne()` I believe. We need to use `.update()` only. In case you want to use `updateOne()`, you need to use the `$set/$unset` field operator to modify the values. Please refer `updateOne()` documentation below. The first parameter is just a filter and only the second parameter carries updated info.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your desired result like this:

```
exports.reldata = async (req, res) => {
  const subject = req.body.subjects;
  const filter = { _id: req.params.id };
  const updateDoc = {
    $set: {
      subjects: subject,
    },
  };
  const result = await SingleCourse.updateOne(filter, updateDoc);
  console.log(
    `${result.matchedCount} document(s) matched the filter, updated ${result.modifiedCount} document(s)`
  );
};
```